# What is my broadcast address

Tags: networking, ip, ip-address, broadcast, subnet

I'm on a network where my machine is 10.0.0.81 and the subnet mask is 255.255.255.0. I'm trying to find out my broadcast address. Would that be 10.0.0.255? If so, how can I validate this? Can I send a ping for example and see which computers it hits?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

your broadcast address is 10.0.0.255, and there is no computer with such address, as it is "logical address"

to find out broadcast address you need YOUIP | ~MASK